# How to create custom compare Attribute for view model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, validation

I write mvc 3 application. I should compare two properties. For example:

```
 public class RenameCompare
 {
       public string OldName { get; set; }
       public string NewName { get; set; }
 }
```

And I want to create Attribute which is should be return comparison result and in necessary case take the Error message. So in result I want that ModelState  return true or false. If properties not equals then return true ModelState.IsValid else return false. Everybody can me help ????

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Here I create the custom NotEqual attribute.

```
public class RenameCompare
    {

        public string OldName { get; set; }

        [NotEqual(PropName="OldName", ErrorMessage="The oldname and new name are equal!")]
        public string NewName { get; set; }
    }
    public class NotEqualAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string PropName { get; set; }


        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            PropertyInfo otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(PropName);

            var otherPropertyStringValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString();

            if (Equals(value.ToString(),otherPropertyStringValue))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```